# How to control child view model from parent view model in xamarin mvvmCross?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a parent view model. Let's call it `ParentViewModel`. In `ParentView.axml` I have this `MvxListView` code:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/childlistitem"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items" />
```

So it is obvious that I have `ChildListItemViewModel` as well...

Now each Item has some parameters inside such as "Id, name,...." besides that my each Item has two buttons: "Edit" and "Delete". This looks like this:

[image]

For example I need to delete one Item. I don't know how to bind click event to the `ParentViewModel` instead of `ChildListItemViewModel`... How could I do that?

I tried to bind click to this kind of parameter that calls command from parent view model:

```
public IMvxCommand<ParentViewModel> Delete => new MvxCommand<ParentViewModel>(x =>
{
    x.DeleteCommand.Execute(Id);
});
```

but `x` is always null, so I'm out of the thoughts....

In other words.. How can I bind parent view model command on child click?